# Query by chaining joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Could you please help me out with this query? I still can't figure out how to achieve that.

There is a team model that has users and lists.

team

```
has_many :lists
has_many :users
```

And there is also a many to many relationship between users and lists that represents which lists the user has access to.

```
list
has_many :accesses
has_many :users, through: :accesses
belongs_to :team

user
has_many :accesses
has_many :lists, through: :accesses
belongs_to :team

access
belongs_to :list
belongs_to :user
```

I would like to get all the lists that belong to the users' team, but which user don't have access too.

I tried this, but that doesn't seem right:

```
List.joins(:team).joins(:user).where.not(users: { id: @user.id })
```

I also have a method called team.lists that allows to grab all lists of a team, but joins doesn't work on it.

Answer (score -1):

What about splitting this a bit?

```
users_lists_ids = @user.lists.pluck(:id)
@user.team.lists.where('id NOT IN (?)', users_lists_ids)
```